# Cannot find file in the gallerie after downloading it with PhoneGap in Android

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, download

i have a problem with the the downloaded files in my PhoneGap-App for Android.
The [download-Function from PhoneGap](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.0.0/cordova_file_file.md.html#FileTransfer) actually works quite well i think. It gets the file from the URL and
stores it on the SD-Card. (Code is below)

So where is the Problem? When I download a JPG or PNG to the
Download-folder, i want it be accessible through the native Gallery.
But the picture don´t appear in the gallerie. To see it I have to
restart the phone or I have to use another App like Astro.

Is there a "Refresh_the_native_Gallerie"-Function or something like that?

Thank you very much.

```
try {
     var filePath = 'file:///mnt/sdcard/Download/google.png'; // Correct filePath
     var url = "https://www.google.de/images/srpr/logo3w.png"; //Correct URL

     var fileTransfer = new FileTransfer();

     fileTransfer.download(url, filePath, function(entry) {
         console.log("s3_download download complete: " + entry.
         // Do i need a "Refresh_all_other_Apps"-function here?
     }, function(error) {
     // Normally no Error
         console.log("s3_download download error source " + error.source);
         console.log("s3_download download error target " + error.target);
         console.log("s3_download download error code" + error.code);
     });
} catch (e) {
     console.log("downloadTest ERROR: " + e);
}
```

---

Cannot answer my own question so fast only edit my question. So here is the answer:

I wrote a little PhoneGap-Plugin, which does actually nothing more than calling the code from zapl. Thanks again. Hope it will help someone with the same problem.

You can find the code here: https://github.com/philipp-at-greenqloud/pluginRefreshMedia

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote a little PhoneGap-Plugin, which does actually nothing more than calling the code from zapl. Thanks again. 
Hope it will help someone with the same problem.

You can find the code here: https://github.com/philipp-at-greenqloud/pluginRefreshMedia

Answer (score 5):

I don't know if that helps you in PhoneGap / JavaScript context:

Your problem is that the gallery will only display files that are indexed in the device media-database. Just adding a file to the file system will not automatically add it to that database. And pretty much the only time a rescan / update of that database happens is when you reboot the device or remount the sdcard (after it was shared with a PC or in case you ejected it and put it back in).

To have a file added to the database the simplest way to to that is to send [Intent#ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE) to the MediaScanner to let it add your file to the database. Once that is done the file will show up in the gallery.

Java code for that would be

```
File newImage = new File("/mnt/sdcard/Download/google.png");
Intent scanIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE);
scanIntent.setData(Uri.fromFile(newImage));
sendBroadcast(scanIntent);
```

Comment: What @zapi says is 100% correct. In PG we'd need to do an add to gallery plugin to add the functionality you are looking for.

Comment: Yes it helps me :) I'm going to create a plugin now. Thank you both.

Answer (score 0):

This is a well needed plugin. I have been trying to do work arounds for this issue and the plugin works a treat. I was looking at developing one myself, but you have done a great job. My headaches are now subsiding. This works for me.

Comment: nice. I am glad that it helped you :) If you find errors, just let me know :)