# How to save base64 images into device using Cordova application?

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-cli

How to save base64 images into device Gallery using cordova Application.i am getting base64 text as response.

Answer (score 0):

You can find here http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/native/base64-to%20gallery/

http://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/80/how-to-convert-a-image-from-the-device-to-base64-with-javascript-in-cordova

https://cordovablogsblogs.wordpress.com/2015/05/29/phonegap-plugin-to-convert-base64-string-to-a-png-image-in-android/

[Reference code from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29288684/phonegap-save-base64-image-to-gallery)

```
window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, function (fileSystem) {

  var fileTransfer = new FileTransfer();
  var uri = encodeURI("http://www.example.com/image");
  var path = fileSystem.root.toURL() + "appName/example.jpg";

  fileTransfer.download(
    uri,
    path,
    function(entry) {
      refreshMedia.refresh(path); // Refresh the image gallery
    },
    function(error) {
      console.log(error.source);
      console.log(error.target);
      console.log(error.code);
    },
    false,
    {
      headers: {
        "Authorization": "dGVzdHVzZXJuYW1lOnRlc3RwYXNzd29yZA=="
      }
    }
  );

});
```

Comment: instant of var uri = encodeURI("http://www.example.com/image");  Shall i pass base64 data

Comment: I am passing like this but image not download into device     
  var uri = encodeURI("iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAMQAAACACAYAAABUb8YRAAAAAXNSR0IArs4c6QAAAARnQU1BAACxjwv8YQUAAAA");
  var path = "file:///storage/emulated/0/example.jpg";

Comment: Now i am passing iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAMQAAACACAYAAABUb8YRAAAAAXNSR0IArs4c6QAAAARnQU1BAACxjwv8YQUAAAAJcEhZcwAADsMAAA7DAcdvqGQAAHFwSURBVHhe7f0FfFVX2j2OQ72duuvUBdpSoa641NupQ0tboC3u7hA8kEBCnBBCXIhBAsTd3d3dXWH91rPPDTAznXfm  Now also not working,With out encode/decode

Comment: var image = new Image();
image.src = 'data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0K...';
document.body.appendChild(image);

Comment: this is my code


var folderpath = "file:///storage/emulated/0/";
var image = new Image(); image.src = 'data:image/png;base64,'+realData; document.body.appendChild(image);
var uri=realData;
download(folderpath,image);

Comment: Yes Singh,But i want to save in device,image src image appering good.