# How to add a Phonegap java plugin in Ionic?

Tags: java, android, cordova, ionic-framework

I am using Ionic to make an app and I have the same problem as this :
[Cannot find file in the gallerie after downloading it with PhoneGap in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11954604/cannot-find-file-in-the-gallerie-after-downloading-it-with-phonegap-in-android)

When I download a Picture in my app it's not updating android media storage.

So I wanted to set up this plugin in my ionic app :
https://github.com/philipp-at-greenqloud/pluginRefreshMedia

But I don't know where should I put the Java file ?
I couldn't find any tutorial for Java plugins in Ionic.

Best regards

Comment: It's simple just put it into the plugins folder and then add the plugin into config.xml file.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add a phonegap plugin to your Ionic project from the command line using:

```
cordova plugin add https://github.com/philipp-at-greenqloud/pluginRefreshMedia
```

I would also recommend adding [ngCordova](http://ngcordova.com/) to your project and learning a bit about it as it will make life easier when dealing with plugins and such.

Comment: I already tried "cordova plugin add https://github.com/philipp-at-greenqloud/pluginRefreshMedia" but I got this error "ENOENT, no such file or directory '/tmp/git/1429083397394/plugin.xml'"

Comment: the plugin is very old, it doesn't support CLI installation, fork it and add a plugin.xml

Comment: I started to create the file plugin.xml following the documentation, but I realized that there is a phonegap dependency in the Java file and in the Javascript file, I am using Ionic to build the app so I don't have Phonegap inside, what can I do ?

Answer (score 0):

I finally used the plugin Canvas2Image that I forked and edited :
https://github.com/sandoche/Canvas2ImagePlugin